# Is it okay to mount a partition in C:\Users\Name\Downloads folder in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, mount

I have a small sized SSD for `C:` drive, and space is running low. A large portion of the files that I have stored in `C:` drive are in the `C:\Users\Name\Downloads` folder. I also use a HDD for other storage.

I recently found out that, on Windows I can mount hard disk partitions in any folder, just like Linux. So I'm planning to move all my files from the `Downloads` folder to another partition which has much space left, and then mount this partition to the (recently emptied) `Downloads` folder.

What I want to know if this will create any unforeseen problems.

Also, the same question can be asked if another partition can be mounted on `C:\Users` or `C:\Users\Name` directly, which can be even more convenient for similar cases.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see any issue with moving the Downloads to the second partition. Also Pictures, documents are all libraries and can be set to other location than defautlt [image]

Comment: And you can do the same for *Documents*, *Music*, *Pictures* and  *Videos*, if you have not yet moved them.